# Kurento : Events from custom module A blocked by Custom module B operations

Tags: kurento

I have created a couple of custom module to process audio for Kurento-group call application.

[image: Custom module arrangement]

The problem which I am facing is that the events raised by `Module A` in image are blocked by `Module C`. and the events arrive at the application server when `Module C's` internet operation is completed. I have used curl for calling a webservice.

Can anyone explain why my events from `Module A` are being delayed/blocked ?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way gstreamer works. The thread that you are using to make http request is blocking the thread that is pushing events in module A.

I think that I warned you about making http requests on the modules, specially if they are being done on the streaming thread. In general, streaming thread should be used for media, not for other blocking operations.

Comment: so like in the image I connect outgoing media to `Module A` , `HubPort` and `Module B` this isn't forking/parallel processing  the outgoing media ? also webservice request is done from another p_thread from inside the module.

Comment: Yes, it's parallel process (ie, different threads are being used) but as long as they are syncronized (because they are passing buffers among each other) when the amount of buffers that can be stored is reached, other threads became to stop too.

Comment: No, sorry, there is nothing for that at the moment. For your problem, try o open a new thread for http requests maybe this will avoid your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you talking about.

Comment: What I meant was : we are having a separate `p_thread` for curl request in out custom filter but still its blocking the main thread execution

Comment: Are this thread synchronized in any way with the streaming thread? I mean, if the thread is doing a request, the streaming thread has to wait until it finishes? Or is there a queue of tasks?

Comment: we have used `g_async_queue` to maintain data which needs to be sent to the webservice, and we have used new `p_thread` everytime we make a webrequest but still we are facing this problem

Comment: Hi, I know this is not relevant to this question but can you tell me how to disable kurento media server debug logs getting looged into log files? I only want Error logs to be generated into the log files. Thanks